# Cornerstone Trunk, Branch, Tags setup

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I am trying out Cornerstone SVN client and I need some help. I am pretty comfortable with the concepts of SVN although I'm very new.

When I create a local repository there is no trunk, tags, branches folders created by default.  Here is my workflow to set up locally and I would like to get your opinions to see if this is okay and what the best way to go about this is.

1. Create a New Repository in folder called 'SVN Repositories' currently in Dropbox folder.
2. Right-click in repository and create a new folder. It gives option for creating 'trunk', 'branches' and 'tags' subfolders core. This folder containing the subfolder is called 'core'.
3. I then import files into trunk from the working folder 'First Repository' on desktop.
4. Files within trunk are 'Checked Out' to the same folder 'First Repository' on desktop.

Things are now in sync.

Any help appreciated to get my head round this. Seems like quite a bit of effort. I thought Cornerstone would have set up Trunk etc automatically?

Thanks,
CD

Answer (score 0):

Very old, but good question.

The answer is that Cornerstone would have a challenge doing this in a standard way for you because there is no standard.  There are only recommendations: trunk/branches/tags at the root of the repo is just a convention.

By the way, don't share your Dropbox folder with an svn repo in it with someone else, or even with yourself on a different machine (at the risk you are running both machines at the same time).   Simultaneous changes to the same file in dropbox as a result of svn actions will break it.